# PostgreSQL 9.4.10 - CREATE DATABASE throws ERROR: permission denied to create database

Tags: permission-denied, postgresql-9.4

- Postgres version: PostgreSQL 9.4.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
- Postgres server is installed using Vagrant with user account created at the time the VM was provisioned.
- Steps I did to login and use psql command:

  - ssh to the server
  - sudo su - postgres
  - PGUSER=username PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost myapp

Than I issue the command in psql:
myapp=> CREATE DATABASE myDB;
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
myapp=>

Can anyone tell me what do I miss? thanks

Comment: Why the `-` in the second step? I guess the command is `sudo su postgres`

Comment: @Polak I tried both and they have the same effect which is log in as postgres user. The main point is why user "username" can not create DB. Even though I also tried ALTER USER username CREATEDB;

Comment: did you try using the bash command createdb as postgres user?
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-createdb.html